# image and the code broke down when generating the pdf using prawn, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I am using prawn gem for generating pdf in ROR. Everything was going very smoothly before working with images. When I am trying to insert an image into the pdf the image is drawn well. But, if the image is located in end of the page in pdf or if the image exceeds the page height then the image gets broke down and the pdf data after the image also gets broken. Please find the image that I have attached for this issue[image]

In the image after the Buildout text, the image is getting broke down and the pdf data after that image also broke down.

I am using 
**gem 'prawn', '2.0.1'**
**gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0'**
for the pdf generation and ruby **ruby 2.1.2p95**

any one can help me on this. Thanks for advance for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the prawn gem. But you can try your luck with [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). This is also one of the gem most developers use to generate pdf. You can have customized CSS for the pdf layout. Hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: i have already done all the work with the prawn. it took lot of time for me to complete this because i am newbie to this. Can you please suggest me with the PRAWN gem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed the gem that you have told. But the result is same. When a image exceeds the page. The image went to invisible. How can we create a page if the image is greater than the page size.

Comment: its late but not the least @Deepak. Thanks for your suggestion, i just changed from prawn to wickedpdf. Thats awesome, works too good. my vote to u.

Answer (score 0):

You can always control :height, :width and :at (location) of the image in Prawn:

```
 Prawn::Document.generate("images.pdf", :page_layout => :landscape) do     
  photo1 = "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/images/photo1.jpg" 
  image photo1, :at => [50,450], :width => 450, :height => 450                                      
 end
```

So you can manage if is located in end of the page or if the image exceeds the page height.

You can define size (height) like this:

```
# New document, A4 paper, landscaped (height = 841.89)
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4", :page_layout => :landscape)

# New document, Custom size (height = 300)
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => [200, 300])
```

Comment: @manfergo25m, thanks for the reply. And i tried in that scenario but it is not allowing me to find the page height. Can you please tell me how to find the page height?